# How to decode latin characters in PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I'm sending an email through phpMailer and here is the body

```
$mail->Body = '<p>Bonjour '.$firstName.'</p><p>Votre compte a été créé avec succès. Vous pouvez dès à présent l\'utiliser. Ci-dessous, je vous prie de trouver le lien qui vous permet d\'accéder à votre compte. Nous vous recommandons de garder ce lien à porter de vous.</p><p>Votre lien: <a href='.$resetUrl.'>'.$resetUrl.'</a></p><p>Note: vous devez enregistrer votre mot de passe, sous 30 jours. Dans le cas contraire, le lien sera espirer et votre compte sera bloqué.</p><p>Bien cordialement,</p><p>Votre Equipe Virtual Visible Hands.</p>';
```

the problem is when I received the email it look like this

Bonjour trek

```
Votre compte a Ã©tÃ© crÃ©Ã© avec succÃ¨s. Vous pouvez dÃ¨s Ã  prÃ©sent l'utiliser. Ci-dessous, je vous prie de trouver le lien qui vous permet d'accÃ©der Ã  votre compte. Nous vous recommandons de garder ce lien Ã  porter de vous.

Votre lien: this is reset url

Note: vous devez enregistrer votre mot de passe, sous 30 jours. Dans le cas contraire, le lien sera espirer et votre compte sera bloquÃ©.

Bien cordialement,

Votre Equipe Virtual Visible Hands.
```

I don't know what character set to be used to fix this. please help thank you.

Comment: Did you try `$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: @vladatr yeah! it worked  . thanks!

Comment: That's correct - The reason it works is that the character set you're providing text in must match the named character set your message is using - you're putting in UTF-8, so you need to tell PHPMailer that. You could achieve the same result (at least in French) using ISO-8859-1 (which is PHPMailer's default) by converting your UTF-8 content to ISO-8859-1.